# Method to return null from a try...catch

Tags: c#, null, return, try-catch

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        if(itemCol != null)
            return itemCol;
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method must return null (not an empty list) - regardless of whether an exception is caught or not. The above works - but is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I just don't understand why you need `if-else`.

Comment: You could just do in the try: return itemCol; instead of the if/else.

Comment: If `itemCol` is an _empty_ list (a collection instance containing 0 items), it will still be returned.

Comment: Naturally, you have to follow the specs. But the specs are making a mistake by requiring callers to check for null before using the collection. Invariably, someone will forget to check for null, and will receive a `NullReferenceException`. The use of exceptions keeps you from having to write code that has to remember to check for error codes since, if there is an "error", then an exception will be thrown, which can be caught by code that knows how to handle it (and _only_ code which knows how to handle it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that your current implementation works. I assume that the method used to get item collection returns either a collection with 1 or more items or null or throws an exception. If this true this would be one alternative.

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
   SPListItemCollection itemCol = null;
   try
   {
      itemCol = //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      LogException(e);
   }
   return itemCol;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(itemCol != null)
    return itemCol;
else
    return null;
```

simplifies to

```
return itemCol;
```

since if `itemCol == null` then returning `itemCol` already returns `null`. No reason to special case that behavior.

If you want to replace empty collections by `null`, you need to use something like:

```
if((itemCol != null) && itemCol.Any())
    return itemCol;
else
    return null;
```

---

A bit of design advice:

- Swallowing exceptions is discouraged. You should only catch a few specific exception you know how to handle
- Empty collections are often nicer to work with than `null`.

Answer (score 4):

I must first say this is an awful thing to do, swallowing exceptions is TERRIBLE! DO NOT DO THIS! It will haunt you and make debugging very very difficult, even worse is returning null because of an exception - the null will typically end up throwing a NullReferenceException which will be far harder to debug than the exception that's being swallowed (even if it's logged), but since you asked:

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    SPListItemCollection itemCol = null;
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
    return itemCol;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Never liked a method with multi-exit-point,
In your **catch** set **itemCol** to null, outside the **try/catch** return itemCol

```
try
{
     // whatever
     if(itemCol.Count == 0) itemCol = null;
}
catch(Exception x)
{
     LogException(x);
     itemCol = null;
}
return itemCol;
```

Comment: This returns empty list not null

Answer (score 1):

To check weather a collection is empty, the `Any()` method is usefull, mostly if you don't have lists, but general IEnumerables.
If you just want to get rid of the duplication of `return null;`, you can easily do so:

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        if(itemCol.Any())
            return itemCol;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can also append a

```
    finally
    {
        // Stuff that always needs to be done.
    }
```

directly after the closing bracket of your `catch`.

Comment: Remove the line `if(itemCol != null)` and I'll give you a +1.

Comment: Thats what I was doing right after seeing the other answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's already good, imo, I would also remove the last `else`, like this:

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        if(itemCol != null)
            return itemCol;

        //Some if/else code here presumably... 

        //NO ELSE HERE...
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would remove the `if` as well :)

Comment: @Tigran this does not make sense if `itemCol` is null `return itemColl` will be the same as `return null`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I **suppose** there are some other code too in the middle. Just suggested with caution.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: I as I explained, I **suppose** the function code is not such simple as it presented. Cause the question is not about the code, but try/catch handling. That is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if-else` block, because you already return null if object is null:

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        return itemCol;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? If your spec says:

> must return null (not an empty list)

Your current implementation will return an empty collection if the collection is not null, but empty. Unless you rely on the method to handle it.

This takes care of that...

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        if(itemCol != null && itemCol.Count == 0)
            return itemCol;

        return itemCol;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do so:

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        return itemCol != null && itemCol.Count == 0 ? null : itemCol;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. If it fits your tastes better you can put the null return at the end:

```
public SPListItemCollection GetACollection()
{
    try
    {
        //Method to get an item collection from somewhere
        if(itemCol != null)
            return itemCol;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the following:

> *from IDesign Coding Standard v2.4 (http://idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1985):*
>
> > 18. Catch only exception for which you have explicit handling.

Let the caller of the method to implement try/catch and handle the exception. I would say it is generally a bad practice to return null on exception because you are hiding the information from the caller and preventing the framework from collecting the proper call stack. And why is that throwing the exception in the first place? Again, catch the explicit exception type that you know of and then handle it. Do not catch other/all exceptions.